# Showing that if any non-zero $f \in X^*$ takes its maximum value on the unit sphere at most once, then X is strictly convex

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $(X, \| \|)$ be a normed space. I'm trying to show that if all non-zero $f \in X^*$ take their maximum value on the unit sphere at most once, i.e. $\forall f \in X^* - \{0\}$ there is at most one point $x \in S(X)$ such that $\langle f, x \rangle = \| f \|$, then $(X, \| \|)$ is strictly convex.

Let $f \in X^* - \{0\}$ such above and, in addition, $\|f\| = 1$. Let $u, v \in X, u \neq v, \|u\| = \|v\| = 1$ and $t \in (0, 1)$.

Whereas $$\langle f, x \rangle = \|f\| = 1$$ it follows that $$\langle f, u\rangle \leq 1\;\;\; \text{ and }\;\;  \langle f, v \rangle \leq 1,$$ but one of the above inequalities must be strict, because $u \neq v$.

Then
$$\langle f, t u + (1-t) v \rangle = t  \langle f, u \rangle + (1-t) \langle f, v \rangle < t + 1 - t = 1.$$
So 
$$\langle f, t u + (1-t) v \rangle < 1.$$ 
And then? How can I show that $\|t u + (1-t) v\| < 1$?

Thank you!

Comment: Try assuming, without loss of generality, that $\langle f, v \rangle < 1$.

Comment: Normed spaces are by definition closed under addition and scalar multiplication of their elements. So if $u, v \in X$ then $tu + (1-t)v \in X$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Thus $X$ is convex.

Comment: But I want X be strictly convex.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of the terminology 'strictly' convex.